# Reading in all docs (doc id only if possible) from Solr without searching

Tags: solr, solrj

I know Solr is meant to be used for searching.

However, I am doing some benchmarking and I wonder if there is a way to retrieve doc id of every document indexed.

The best option is retrieving without searching (if there exist a way).

I guess the alternative is to query all documents but only asks for doc id.

I will be using SolrJ, so operations of SolrJ would be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `/export` end point: [Exporting result sets](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/exporting-result-sets.html).

It supports using the same `fl` parameter as regular search (although searching for just `*:*` will probably behave quite similar when you're using SolrJ).

In SolrJ you'll have to use the `CloudSolrStream` class instead to properly stream the results (as compared to the regular behavior when searching for `*:*`).

From [Joel Bernstein's example when introducing the feature](http://joelsolr.blogspot.com/2015/04/the-streaming-api-solrjio-basics.html):

```
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class StreamingClient {

   public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
      String zkHost = args[0];
      String collection = args[1];

      Map props = new HashMap();
      props.put("q", "*:*");
      props.put("qt", "/export");
      props.put("sort", "fieldA asc");
      props.put("fl", "fieldA,fieldB,fieldC");

      CloudSolrStream cstream = new CloudSolrStream(zkHost, 
                                                    collection, 
                                                    props);
      try {

        cstream.open();
        while(true) {

          Tuple tuple = cstream.read();
          if(tuple.EOF) {
             break;
          }

          String fieldA = tuple.getString("fieldA");
          String fieldB = tuple.getString("fieldB");
          String fieldC = tuple.getString("fieldC");
          System.out.println(fieldA + ", " + fieldB + ", " + fieldC);
        }

      } finally {
       cstream.close();
      }
   }
}
```